Twilio iOS SDK monitor remote participant audio levels
I would like to monitor audio levels of the remote participant.
Is it possible to detect when the remote participant is speaking or the audio levels are changing? My goal is to determine when the remote participant is speaking and adding an observer to the RemoteAudioTrack does not work in this case.
SDK: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/ios/get-started
Example code:
extension VideoCallViewController: RemoteParticipantDelegate {

func localParticipantDidPublishAudioTrack(participant: LocalParticipant, audioTrackPublication: LocalAudioTrackPublication) {
    print("did publish audio track")
}

func didSubscribeToAudioTrack(audioTrack: RemoteAudioTrack, publication: RemoteAudioTrackPublication, participant: RemoteParticipant) {
    print("Subscribed to remote audio track for participant \(participant.identity)")
    // Monitor audio levels
    monitorAudioLevels(audioTrack: audioTrack)
}

func monitorAudioLevels(audioTrack: RemoteAudioTrack) {
    print("in monitoring audio levels")
    
    // Assuming audioTrack provides a way to monitor audio levels
    audioTrack.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "audioLevel", options: .new, context: nil)
}


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("in observe")
        guard let audioTrack = object as? RemoteAudioTrack, keyPath == "audioLevel" else {
            print("Observer guard failed")
            return
        }
        
        print("Observer guard passed")
        if let audioLevel = change?[.newKey] as? Float {
            // Threshold for detecting speech
            let threshold: Float = 0.1
            
            if audioLevel > threshold {
                print("Remote participant is speaking with audioLevel: \(audioLevel)")
                startTranscribing()
            } else {
                print("Remote participant is silent with audioLevel: \(audioLevel)")
                stopTranscribing()
            }
        }
    }

}


There is no direct API. But you can use stats callback:
getStats()

And you can use RemoteAudioTrackStats object which contains audioLevel
For reference check this link
https://twilio.github.io/twilio-video-ios/docs/latest/Classes/TVIRemoteAudioTrackStats.html
Discussion for same: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-ios/issues/120

ive looked into this but how would I consistently call getStats() to get audio levels? Would I have to use a timer to achieve this?

@adalovelacy Did you find any solution?
